# Waiting for multiple WebSocket callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, callback, promise

I'm initializing a page using multiple **WebSocket queries** (I receive the results via the onmessage event and then call the right callback function for each message I receive).

i.e:

```
query("get_users",callback1);
query("get_weather",callback2);
...
```

Now I want to display a loader (spinner) and make it disappear only after all the data has been loaded (all callbacks are done). I know that I can make the callbacks update a counter, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this, if possible.

I tried using JQuery Promises but couldn't understand how to use it with WebSockets (instead of Ajax calls).

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promisify it:

```
function request(url){
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
   query(url,resolve);
 });
}
```

Then you can use Promise.all:

```
Promise.all([request("get_users"),request("get_weather")])
 .then(function([users,weather]){
   console.log(users,weather);
});
```

If you want to seperate the data handler and the spinner, simply make the Promises globally available:

```
var users=request("get_users"),
  weather=request("get_weather");

weather.then(function(weather){
  //show weather
});
//same with users

loader.show();//show some spinner
Promise.all([weather,users]).then(loader.hide);//hide if all loaded
```

Comment: what if the queries are initiated from different files? (i.e: one file queries the users and handle the results, another file query the weather, etc...)

Comment: @OmriSoudry expose the promises to global variable, e.g. var weather=request("get_weather"); , then you can put it into Promise.all everywhere...